# Cannot hardcode a role when creating a user

Tags: node.js, express, roles

I get an error like:

> "role: 'User' SyntaxError: missing after argument list"

when trying to hard code the role of user when creating the user.

My register function

```
  async register (req, res) {
    try {
      const user = await User.create(
        req.body.username,
        req.body.email,
        req.body.password,
        req.body.firstName,
        req.body.lastName,
        role: 'User'
      )
      const userJson = user.toJSON()
      res.send({
        user: userJson,
        token: jwtSignUser(userJson)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(400).send({
        error: 'This email account is already in use.'
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Aren't you missing parenthesis in create function User.create({*}) ?

Comment: I tried that already and I get the following error:  `req.body.username, SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: You are not using es6 feature properly - you parameter is req.body.username you cannot simply add like above in your code - you need to do {username: req.body.username ,etc}.

Comment: If you were having a parameters username, email you could have simply used ({username, email})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.create` call is incorrect. It expected an object while a list of arguments was given and `role: 'User'`, which is syntax error.

If it needs some fields from `req.body` and `role` field, it should be:

```
...
const { username, email } = req.body;
const user = await User.create({ username, email, role: 'User' });
...
```